# Correlation between two text columns Python (text Analytics)

Tags: python, r, text-analysis

How can I find the correlation between the frequency of specific values in multiple text columns? These columns contain specific tags like: 'Indicator Discrepancy','Missing or Invalid', or 'Inaccurate'.

I would like to figure out which values in the first sheet are correlated with changes in values in the second list.

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered here. StackOverflow is for specific programming questions; you should look at tutorials about text analytics to get started, then come back with a new question once you have some code to show and **specific** questions to ask about it. Good luck!

Comment: Why is this tagged R?